# How to call a control center play button to play audio in background using code

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, avaudiosession, control-center

I am playing **Videos** in UIWebView and using the below code to play its **audio** in background.

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
            print("AVAudioSession is Active")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

The problem is that when I press Home Button, AVAudioSession do not play music automatically until I tap a **play** button in Toggle or **control center** menu. 
Also when I tap Play button, it hides seek track duration and music info, when I pause music then it show.

I have attached a control center image which shows what I need for videos.[image]

Please guide me how to fix it?
Thanks